# Workflow not working properly

Tags: workflow

The workflow image is attached. I have fields such as Assigned to and Assigned by. Assigned to user receives an email when he is assigned an assignment. When the assigned to user completes the assignment and changes the status to "completed", the assigned to person gets an email. However, the assigned by person is supposed to get the email. In sharepoint task view, the assigned by person it still shows "started" and not "completed", even though the assigned to user marked it completed.

Is my workflow wrong. I don't understand why assigned by person is not getting an email saying assignment has been completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start your workflow the default status is started then your workflow send an email then end your workflow!

So it didn't send an email when the status is completed because the workflow already ended.

Try to use `wait for` action to wait until the status changed to completed.

> Note: Use your fields name with the above actions orders!

[image]

> **Note:** make sure the `assigned by` is a people picker field or you can also use the `created by` field if it's the requester who assigned the new
>   assignment